# Brightness Control Software

Tags: windows, display

I'm looking for a simple utility to control brightness **on multiple monitors at the same time**

That is, if I turn brightness down/up it should decrease/increase on both my laptop screen and external monitor.

Comment: There is [Monitorian](https://github.com/emoacht/Monitorian), but it does not work for my ASUS MG279 via Displayport and it does not recognize my VGA monitor at all. Maybe it works for you it you have displays connected via HDMI

Comment: so cool, it works great.. yes I have hdmi right now with my portable monitor setup.

Comment: If you like, you can write an answer yourself. I can't honestly recommend it, because it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monitorian works pretty good, see comments on the question above. See links there too. Everything pertinent is mentioned there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).